# File id encryption using php

Tags: php, database, security, encryption, qr-code

I am storing users' file uploads in my DB. the website is made in PHP. The user can get his file in QRcode form to share it with others. Problem comes while scanning the unique file id of the file is visible.What type of encryption should I use to hide the file id in QRcode when scanned & how?

Comment: More details are needed because we have no idea how your application is done: 1. how, where and to whom is the QRcode  visible? 2. If visible: what security concerns are you worried about?

Comment: Basically we have a dedicated qrcode app. however when the qrcode is scanned by an outside app, the file id is visible. I want to avoid this, What should I do?

Comment: I'm going to vote to close because StackOverflow is not "free cryptography engineering for vague questions as a service". You'll want to hire an expert.